# Continuous integration services and local unit tests?

Tags: git, unit-testing, continuous-integration

I am looking to implement a continuous integration service on our development server, which currently only hosts SVN/GIT and an issue tracker...

How does this work in theory? If a CI is ran on push/commit requests and the operation fails if any of the unit tests/QA fail...do you run tests locally before even trying or is this redundant now due to the CI server performing this before commit?

I am developing in a WAMP/LAMP environment so of course my setup is complex :p

Answer (score 1):

A CI server does not run unit tests before the commit is done, but after it.

Even the CI server runs tests or not, you should run tests locally before committing anything, so you will check that your work is fine, and then the CI server will check that your work is fine after integrate it with the rest of the team work.

Said that, you have many options on internet for CI services, like http://travis-ci.com or http://clinkerhq.com